# how to delete all row that contains the specific value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains user's permission. I want to delete all records which user_id =`$user_id`
I tried this code below but it seems to delete only 1 record per query.
I have table like this:

```
`user_id` `cat1` `cat2` `cat3`
 100       1000   2000   3000
 100       1000   2000   3001
 200       2500   2501   3000
 100       3000   3500   3333
```

and so on.
my query doesn't seem to work properly and delete all records which are equal to `$user_id`.suppose `$user_id=100;`

```
<?php
  $query="DELETE FROM tbl WHERE user_id=".$user_id;
  mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure the `$user_id` was equal to 100?

Comment: If $user_id is 100 that will delete all rows where user_id is 100, if it doesn't then either one is not 100 ...

Comment: have you tried running the command from the command line just to check? the query seems to be correct

Comment: mysql_* functions are depreciated, please see [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Try this $query="DELETE FROM tbl WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'";

Comment: At runtime, what is the actual query being executed?  What is the result of executing that same query manually on MySQL?  The `DELETE` command does what you're expecting it to do, something else in your assumptions must be wrong.

Comment: May I ask the 1 million dollar question: _What is the datatype of column `user_id`?_

Answer (score 0):

Query `"DELETE FROM tbl WHERE user_id='".$user_id."'"` will remove all rows where user_id is matching with value you passed as a parameter.

If there is no any match, query will do nothing and that's it.

Regards,
Bojan

Comment: `user_id` almost certainly an integer-type column, so quoting it as a string is unnecessary. The OP indicated that the original query works; it just deletes too few rows. This answer does not address that problem.

Comment: Yes, but he didn't specified it's an integer. 
So what if user_id is actually string ?